# Project Euler Q27: What's wrong with this code?

Tags: python, math

This program is written to solve Project Euler Problem 27:
[Project Euler Problem 27](https://projecteuler.net/problem=27)

Here's the code:

```
   ab=[0,0]
b_list=[]
for x in range(2,1000):
    fact=1
    y=2
    while y*y<=x:
        if x==2:
            break
        if x%y==0:
            fact+=1
            break
        y+=1
    if fact==1:
        b_list.append(x)

number=0
max_=0
for a in range(-999,1000):
    for b in b_list:
        if a<=-b:
            continue
        n=0
        num_of_primes=0
        while True:
            number=((n*n)+(a*n)+b)
            n+=1
            print number
            if number>0:                
                factors=1
                div=2
                while div*div<=number:
                    if number==2:
                        break
                    if number%div==0:
                        factors+=1
                        break
                    div+=1
                if factors==1:
                    num_of_primes+=1
            else:
                break
        if max_<num_of_primes:
            max_=num_of_primes
            ab[0]=a
            ab[1]=b                
print ab[0]*ab[1]
```

But when I run this code, the code stops at a=-63 without giving any output. Can anybody suggest why that happens?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, deleted the traling spaces of the first line and executed (python2.7.5). There is a lot of output.

Comment: ya, but not the final one which i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could have thought about the problem a little bit more. Also, your code looks bit sluggish. Maybe it would help if you coded some functions instead of doing everything in one go. I see a lot of code repetition in there

Anyway, here's my two cents:

The program is probably stuck in the `while True:` cycle infinitely, as you only break out of the cycle when `number <= 0`. I haven't read your code with too much attention, but do you intend to break out of the `while True:` loop with the `break` statements that are inside the `while div*div<=number:` cycle? That is not possible. You would most probably need to have a variable to detect if you exit your loop prematurely and then break from the outer loop. Otherwise, maybe the `else` clause of python loops may help somehow (see [Control Flow in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)).